# How does cin accomplish waiting for user input?

Tags: c++, cin

I am very new to programming. I started learning about loops (while loops, for loops) in C++ in my university course last day.

I always wondered how **"cin"** manages to halt the program and await for user input. Does it use a loop behind the scenes? or does it accomplish this is some other way that I am not familiar with?

Comment: Deep magic.  Where there is an operating system, it will call a lower-level read function that uses OS magic to stop and wait for notification of data arrival. Where there is no operating system it could do wide variety of different things including a [busy spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) loop.

Comment: It blocks, waiting to read from an input stream. It will wait indefinitely until there is input. It's not technically implemented as a loop. In practice, it is implemented using operating system-provided features. But they work in a similar manner, so at this point, thinking of it as a loop that waits until some input or a trigger is provided is a reasonable mental model for you to have.